# Is it possible to recover deleted data from sandbox?

Tags: admin

we have accidently deleted data/records from our development sandbox without any backup. is there any way to recover it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow these simple steps to retrieve your deleted records in sandbox -

> 1. Click on App Launcher
> 2. Search for Recycle Bin and click on it.
> 3. Select records you want to restore and click on restore.

**NOTE: You have to do this within 15 days of record deletion.**